# If sample average converges a.s. in an iid sample, must it converge to the mean?

Tags: convergence, asymptotics, law-of-large-numbers

SLLN tells us that if $X_1,...,X_n$ are iid, with $X_1$ having finite mean $\mu$, then their sample average converges almost surely to $\mu$.

Suppose instead we know that $X_1,...,X_n$ are iid and their sample average converges almost surely to a constant.  Can we argue that the $X_1$ has a finite mean and hence that such a constant must be the mean of $X_1$?

---

Note this is a follow up to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/609952/if-sample-average-converges-in-an-iid-sample-must-it-converge-to-the-mean) question.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thanks for your comment, but these questions are not the same.  This one has a much stronger premise (a.s. convergence to a constant), and I did not say $E[X_1]$ is defined and finite (indeed, the question is whether we can conclude this)---I have edited it now to further emphasize this.

Comment: Is the "constant" a finite real number?